# How to removes a link from iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I hvae iframe code like this

```
    <iframe id="iframe" align="left" style="background-color:#000000" src="//third party url" frameborder="0" height="85" width="300" scrolling="no">
```

Now it generates a link inside body.& i want to remove a link from that.

Any suggestions??

Comment: @Teemu yes it creates a direct link to their website & i want to remove it

Comment: It is very likely against their terms of use that you try to manipulate their page. It all sounds very suspect

Comment: @Teemu in iframe <html> <head> </head> <body> <div> <a //exactly here> </a>...

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe src points to another server than yours, you cannot alter its HTML (the cross-domain restriction).

You can however hide the link by Javascript or CSS if you can control somehow the third party server (a method named JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from the Javascript as it is from external site. Alternately you can do it from server side (either PHP/ASP.NET or others) using CURL or respective syntax to read the content and change before serving. It should work without any issues.